# Where are screen options when in admin on mobile?

Tags: wp-admin, screen-options

I'm working in the WordPress admin area on my smartphone.

### Where are the screen options?

I need to "Show advanced menu properties".

Answer (score 1):

If the screen is less than 782px, "Screen Options" are hidden.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 782px) {

#collapse-menu, #screen-meta, #screen-meta-links, .post-format-select {
  display: none!important;
}

}
```

Comment: That's nice to know, but I can't believe that you have to have a desktop computer or hack the code to properly adminstrate your WP installation. That's so backward. I mean, we are designing mobile first, but the backend is still desktop first. That's plain stupid. Anyway, +1 for helping me understand, although it is not a solution to my problem.

Answer (score -1):

They're hidden. Sign in on a desktop and enable the meta box you want to show -  it's a user setting, not a device setting, so once you're done, the box will show on mobile too.

Comment: I don't have access to a desktop computer for the next few days. So how do I enable them while on mobile?

Comment: This is not correct. Even if you enable them, you won't be able to see them in mobile view.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding - if I enable a meta box, it will be visible regardless of device size (even though on mobile the screen options is hidden).

Comment: +1 for correctly explaining that once activated the activated options are available on mobile, too. Still, this does not help me, if I don't have a desktop computer (which is a serious flaw in WP).